# Need a equivalent code in java streams for iterating list of Object

Tags: java, arraylist, java-stream

Can anyone help me with the stream equivalent code
Note:- I cannot make the studentFinalList "final"

```
List<Student> studentFinalList=new ArrayList<>();
for (Student ep:StudentList) {
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(ep.getName()) && ep.getName() == null) {
        studentFinalList.add(ep);
    }
    else if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(ep.getName()) && 
        !ep.getName().equals("") && ep.getName() != null) {
        if (sIdList.contains(ep.getId())) {
            studentFinalList.add(ep);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some conditions in the code seem to be redundant and may be removed without affecting the logic:

- `StringUtils.isBlank(ep.getName()) && ep.getName() == null` may be shortened to `ep.getName() == null` - because `StringUtils.isBlank` checks for null, empty, or whitespace-only string
- `StringUtils.isNotBlank(ep.getName()) && !ep.getName().equals("") && ep.getName() != null` - there's no need to check for `!name.equals("")` and `null` so only `StringUtils.isNotBlank(ep.getName())` is enough.

Next, list of ids `sIdList` should be converted into set to facilitate look-up of the ids (`O(1)` in sets instead of `O(N)` in list).

Thus, the code may ne simplified as:

```java
Set<String> sIdSet = new HashSet<>(sIdList);
List<Student> studentFinalList = studentList
    .stream()
    .filter(ep -> ep.getName() == null 
        || (!StringUtils.isBlank(ep.getName()) && sIdSet.contains(ep.getId()))
    )
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: no sometimes "Name" can contain blank values or sometime null so we need to verify both

Comment: @TechTravellers, [Apache Commons `StringUtils::isBlank`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isBlank-java.lang.CharSequence-) _Checks if a CharSequence is empty (""), null or whitespace only._  Thus it is pointless to check if a string `isBlank` AND equal to `null` at the same time. If you meant `isBlank AND null` - only null check is needed; if you meant `isBlank OR null` - call only `isBlank`

Answer (score 0):

You can put all the if statements in one `filter`:

```
List<Student> studentFinalList = studentList.stream()
        .filter(ep -> (StringUtils.isBlank(ep.getName()) && ep.ep.getName() == null) ||
                  (StringUtils.isNotBlank(ep.getName()) && !ep.getName().equals("") &&
                          ep.getName() != null && sIdList.contains(ep.getId())))
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Although I would suggest to double check your submitted code, because I suspect it contains some errors, for example `ep.ep.getName()`.